# Reorder hidden tabs in excel

Tags: vba, excel, tabs

At work, we've developed a tool using Excel and VBA. This tool has hidden sheets that will only be opened once the previous step is complete. One of the issues I'm running into from the previous coder is that the very last step, there is an extra button, let's call it A, that can be clicked. Based on the order of sheets the previous coder created, this sheet was second out of 10, and when A is clicked, its automatically goes to the second position.

Is there any way I can modify it to the the right most tab?

The problem I run into is when I get to the final step, I can manually move the tab to the right hand side, but that is only after I have finished my analysis, and can not go to the beginning, so it does not allow me to save.

Answer (score 0):

This will move your hidden sheet to end of all visible sheets:

```
Sub test()

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Visible = True
        Sheets("Sheet1").Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        .Visible = False
    End With

End Sub
```

And this will move your hidden sheet to the end of all hidden and visible sheets:

```
Sub moveHiddenSheet()

Dim ws, x, lastSheet

x = 0
For ws = Worksheets.Count To 0 Step -1
    x = x + 1
    If Sheets(Worksheets.Count - x).Visible = False Then
        Sheets(ws).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        lastSheet = Sheets(ws).Name
        Exit For
    End If
Next ws

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Visible = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Move After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count) 
    .Visible = False
End With

Sheets(lastSheet).Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: It won't work for me. I placed this right where the button is clicked, yet it does nothing different.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand what you're trying to do... are you trying to click a button and move a specific sheet to the right-most tab position? And is the sheet that you want to move hidden or visible?

Comment: Ahhh.. I understand what you mean now, give me a few minutes and I'll update my answer...

Comment: Nevermind, thank you for your help! I just removed the last line, .visible = false, since I still need it to be present